# Relationship one to one (1:1)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, mysql-workbench, relationship

I'm with some doubts about relationship one to one. In my example, i have one company and the company has one address. (the data type are random, only to exemplify)

**Option 1:**

[image: Option 1]

**Option 2:**

[image: Option 2]

What's the best option? I can put all data in same table, i know, but are many attributes for a single table.

Comment: The best option is the one that meets your needs.  In my experience, a company can have multiple addresses, both at the same time and over time.

Comment: Option 1 will require you to create the address first if address_id will be a required value. Option 2 will require the opposite if company_id is required. Or if you add constraints etc etc.

Comment: Third option: use a join-table with columns `(company_id, address_id)` and a unique constraint on both columns. That way your company and address tables can remain unchanged and you link them via the third table. The unique constraint ensures that there are only 1:1 relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I personally try to avoid creating one to one relationships. In your example you have one company that has a relationship with an address. I would simply put the foreign key on the company table which would officially make this a one to many relationship (even if you will never use it like that). So, I would first ask if you can accept to have a model where two companies are allowed to have the same address.

If not, a possible solution for a one to one relationships is to share the same value as the primary key. So that ID 1000 in the company table match ID 1000 in the address table. A lot of ORM tools like EF and Hibernate use this method, there is no good native SQL supported way of doing it, without getting in a lot of problems (cascade deletes to mention one)

Answer (score 1):

I create 1-1 relationships in 2 circumstances:

- the dependent table(`Address` in your case) could be joined with other tables. So I keep it as an standalone entity.
- Abstraction or Specific use case. for example Always I try to keep user & personal data in 2 separate tables.

With that in mind, & while your design doesn't let first case to happen(because of `Company_id` column in it), I will push both tables into One. Don't worry about the size of the table. Its not a big deal in your case.

Answer (score 1):

In the example above, I wouldn't use two tables and a one-to-one relationship. I'd just put everything in one table. I don't personally think you're gaining anything splitting the data over two tables.

The main time I'd use a one-to-one relationship is when inheritance is involved.

Below, a person can be a staff and/or a customer. The staff and customer inherit the person attributes. The advantage being if a person is a staff AND a customer their details are stored only once, in the generic person table. The child tables have details specific to staff and customers.

[image: one-to-one relationship ERD]

Answer (score 0):

I Agree with Fredrik Rudberg. Unless the other table represents an independent entity (this is specific to problem domain) it is not advised to keep into separate table for one to one relationship.
Do you have address table (if created) contributing to any other business need? If not then, wouldn't it be a good idea to appear *address* as attribute (column) for the company entity (*Company* table)?